# Toggling hide and close not working

Tags: jquery

Im trying to get a div to toggle hiding and showing div content but at the moment the code i'm using seems to make the content collapse into the top corner and fade. How do I stop it from doing that and simply expand and collapse up and down without moving text or moving the div from its position without setting a fixed width.

CURRENT JQUERY & FIDDLE

```
$(document).ready(
function() {
    $(".about").click(function() {
        $(".about-content").toggle('slow');
   });
});
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GsBWD/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `slideToggle()`

```
$(document).ready(
function() {
    $(".about").click(function() {
        $(".about-content").slideToggle('slow');
   });
});
```

also, you can use `fadeToggle()` to fade in and out.

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/GsBWD/1/